# Intent.ACTION_CALL terminates calls immediately on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent

My app generates calls as follows (intent is sent from a service):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

It has this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

It works fine on most devices, but only on some (Samsung S6, LG - mostly Lollipop) it sometimes causes the call to terminate immediately (not always, on ~30-40% of the calls).

Logs show that Telecom manager decided mysteriously to disconnect the call:

```
09-30 09:23:01.731    3565-3565/? I/Telecom﹕ : Delayed disconnection of call: [929220936, CONNECTING, null, ***-***-****,
0, childs(0), has_parent(false), [[Capabilities:]]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To just open the dialer app (the user has to press the call button inside the dialer app; no additional permissions needed) use:

```
String number = "9999999999";
Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);             
Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call); 
startActivity(surf);
```

To open the dialer app and do the call automatically (needs android.permission.CALL_PHONE) use:

```
 String number = "9999999999";
    Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);             
    Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call); 
    startActivity(surf);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done (the ACTION_CALL part), but on some devices it opens the dialer and immediately closes it (not deterministic, only sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting the call from within BroadcastReceiver.onReceive ?
I encountered the same problem, it seemed that when the receiver terminates, it takes down the call with it...
This worked for me:

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(callIntent);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```